# How to increase the size of extended partition with free unallocated disk space to the right of it using fdisk/parted utilities?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, disk, fdisk, parted

```
# parted /dev/vda print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 137GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
       32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
       256MB   257MB   1048kB            Free Space
2      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  extended
5      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  logical                lvm
       42.9GB  137GB   94.5GB            Free Space
```

I'm looking to increase the the size of extended partition from the unallocated free space.

Current size of extended partition: 42.7GB Unallocated Free Space available: 94.5GB

How can I use the Unallocated Free Space available: 94.5GB to increase the size of extended partition?

Comment: Please advise which version of Ubuntu is in use. Please also advise if you use Hibernation. Click [edit] and answer those two questions by adding to your original question; please do not use Add Comment but instead use [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Ubuntu flavor and you want to extend the logical partition that to be you are trying to resize or extend the vhd's/sdd on the physical or virtual machine box, if in case my assumption is correct please use the **resizepart**  argument with parted.

**Note: Do not forgot to take the data backup when performing it.**

[image]

And there is another tool called **gparted**, to resize the partition on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gparted from a live CD could be the best solution.
I for instance to resize an extended LBA partition I used Gparted as following:

1. First Download a linux Live CD. "I used Ubuntu Mate live CD".
2. Boot your Computer from the Live CD.
3. From the menu->system menu-> Gparted.
4. Look for partitions with a key icon left to the partition name and umount it right click. for the swap partition right click and no swap.
5. Now I think you will be able to move and resize the extended
   partition.
   If any questions do not hesitate to ask

.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be an active partition to the right of the extended partion you want to resize to include the unallocated space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).